# Error: The operation not method is not implemented

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I wish to load the datatable from database to data grid view,but I get the error saying "The operation & method is not implemented". I do review the video over here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sm5mxkytfWk; This is my very first time to do this, hope to get to solve it.

Below is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constring = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\oo\Documents\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand("SELECT* from Data.itemInfo;", conDataBase);

        try
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmdDataBase;
            DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dbdataset);
            BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

            bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
            sda.Update(dbdataset);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand("SELECT* from Data.itemInfo;", conDataBase);
```

yours Sql query contain extra semicolen

from

```
SELECT* from Data.itemInfo;
```

to

```
SELECT* from Data.itemInfo
```

[How to: Bind Data to the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: I have added this, it return me red lines for "Tables" & "DataBind", then I add in "using System.Data.DataTable;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView;", it does not work...